# Authentication using token. Oauth2 questions

Tags: authentication, service, oauth, token

I need Oauth2 or similar, the problem is that it seems I need third party systems for implementing Oauth2, like google, and I don't want that. I want to be the one to create and give permissions to the client.

**Further explaination:**

I, the server, want to offer a service to the client.
I want to authenticate the client, to give him different permissions about my service.

Client authenticate with username and password, or clientid and secretkey, or whatever.
Then I, the server, create a token and give it to the Client, who will use my service forever or until I decide he lost that privilege.

The token is what I use to know who he is, that grant access to my service but is also revokable.

I tryed to understand oauth2, jwt tokens and much more, but I didn't understood much and, when I did, I found out that wasn't secure at all.
So I beg you for help, what one in my situation should do?

Comment: OAuth 2.0, as with all things, when properly implemented, is secure. Sounds like you need to look at OpenID Connect as you are implying you want authentication. Also, read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry the vague question, maybe I'll try to reformulate, when I wrote it I was in confusion.
OpenID and Oauth2.0 are different and the problem I saw for now is that OAuth2.0 MUST rely on a third party service, like google, etc...
I don't want that, I want to be the one that create and give permissions :(

Comment: You can do that, just run your own OpenID Connect Provider.